# Hide - show with a select [HTML / CSS]

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've searched a moment but I can't find a clear response to my problem, so here it is.

I want to check if a specific option is used inside a select, and if it is this specific option it should hide some part of the code and show others.

Here's an example of what it should do.

```
<select>
    <option value="goblin"> Goblin </option>
    <option value="elf"> Elf </option>
</select>

<div>
    <p> This should appear only if "Elf" is selected </p>
</div>
.
..
...
<p> This should also appear only if "Elf" is selected and is really far away in the code </p>
```

It should be only with CSS, I can't use JS or other langages than HTML & CSS.
Is there a way to do something like that ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: As far as I know, you would need a bit of JS for this. The reason is that you can't go "up the tree" with CSS selectors. So while you could theoretically do something like `option[value="elf"]:checked`, which would target only the `elf` option when it is selected, you have no way of then targeting the appropriate `div` or `p` further down, as they are neither siblings nor children of the `option` elements.